# Display options for GraphData output

Tags: graphs-and-networks

How can the display of graphs using `GraphData` be customized?

For example, how can we customize the vertex style, color, edge thickness of the output to`GraphData["TetrahedralGraph"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GraphPlot` and the many options there.
Specifically for your question the options are `VertexRenderingFunction` and `EdgeRenderingFunction`.
Example:

```
GraphPlot[GraphData["TetrahedralGraph"], 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Red, Thickness[.01], Line[#1]} &),
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({Blue, PointSize[.03], Point[#1]} &)
]
```

Comment: I would recommend using `SetProperty` and the new `Graph` objects (since v8) instead of the deprecated `GraphPlot`.